# JSON/PHP script and callbacks

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a JSON script for my testing site on localhost.
What I am trying to do is get it to display different content, depending on the name of the radio station.

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
  header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

  $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myradio";
  $username=test;
  $password=test;
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
  $rows = array();
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(start, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS start, 
                                   DATE_FORMAT(end, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS end FROM londonradio");
  $stmt->execute();
  $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  echo '{"success":true,"error":"","data":{"schedule":';
  echo json_encode($rows);
  echo "]}}";
?>
```

The code does work, but I still have a bug to iron out; I wanted to be able to select between stations, so that this kind of URL is possible:

http://www.mylocalhostradio.co.uk/schedule.php?callback=?&name=London+FM
http://www.mylocalhostradio.co.uk/schedule.php?callback=?&name=Birmingham+FM

The actual site's domain is http://mylocalhostradio2.co.uk

How can I fix my PHP/JSON so I can do a callback, and when the name variable changes, it displays different content (this is from a MySQL database, not a PHP array)?

I am part of the way there, and would appreciate some help in fixing my script; it does the first thing - displays MySQL as JSON.

Now I just need to get it formatted similar to [here](http://radioplayer.bauerradio.com/schedule.php?callback=?&name=Wave%20105) and be able to change the data displayed in the name bit after the callback.
All advice is appreciated.

Comment: have you used `$_GET` before?

Comment: Do not write your own json... Create a single array/object then json_encode the whole thing. You should only ever have one `echo` in a json webservice.

Comment: @ anurupr - I have rarely used $_GET

Comment: @avenas8808 : What exactly you are trying to do and what you are not getting? add little more explanation.